# fastest integer sort implementation for 200-300 bit integers?

Tags: c++, c, sorting, integer

What is the fastest integer sort implementation for 200-300 bit sized integers? Exact int size is fixed; I have up to 2 gigabytes with such integers (all in RAM).

I hear that it is possible to sort such set in average at O(n log log M) or even at O(n sqrt(log log M)) time, wher n is number of integers and M is the largest integer. Memory usage is limited (I may use up to 0.5-1 GB addtionally). Sorting can be done in-place; in can be unstable (reorder dups).

Is there C/C++ implementation of such sort method, e.g. of  Han & Thorup (2002)?

Comment: are the ints random?  is there any internal pattern that may help?  this is two problems: an efficient large integer comparison and a fast sort function.  there are lots of evaluations of fast sorting algorithms...  you need to find a fast comparison.

Comment: they are not random, but are rather big. I want to test faster signature-based method or  van Emde Boas tree-based method, like "Han&Thorup 2002". I had, but i want to get complete implementation.

Comment: A 300 bit sized integer? [Let me googol it for you](http://www.google.com/search?q=2+^+300&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Perhaps you should also be worried about how much memory your sorting algorithm will take up. Some algorithms work well in-place, others do not.

Comment: I'd bet on a MSD recursive radix sort to be the most efficient from a memory usage and cache locality (very important I think with that amount of data) points of view. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Most_significant_digit_radix_sorts

Comment: Is the range between the smallest and largest value large?

Comment: signed 2's complement or unsigned?

Comment: Also how are two values compared?

Comment: unsigned. numbers can be stored as GMP or GMP-like limb array. Smallest value is around 64-bit sized. Largest value is 10-100 times smaller than full bit size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) can be used to sort data with fixed size keys. As this condition is not often met the technique isn't discussed much, but it can be O(n) when the key size is factored out.

Comment: It is O(n m) where `m` is the size (ie. number of digits) of the greatest integer.

Comment: This was my answer too until I read the question properly. The OP already mentions methods which have an asymptotic runtime that is _better_ than radix sort (O(n log m) or O(n sqrt(log m)) rather than O(n m), for m-bit values). Radix sort may still win for practical reasons, but you haven't mentioned any of these.

Comment: @John, the OP mentions a single algorithm which can't be evaluated by the general public because it's behind a paywall. A little Googling turned up this gem on Wikipedia, but there's still no detailed algorithm descriptions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting As far as complexity goes they're all O(n) with a different constant multiplier based on the key length. The actual time taken will depend as much on the code complexity as the theoretical slicing of the key.

Comment: @Mark: Totally agree that the actual run time will be strongly dependent on implementation factors, in fact I think that's important enough to be included in your answer. However, just telling someone who already knows that sorting can be done in O(n) time that radix sort can sort in O(n) time isn't adding very much. This is based on the assumption (perhaps incorrect) that having investigated enough to find Han & Thorup, the OP would also have come across the (comparatively well known) radix sort.

Comment: @Mark: As for the pay-wall, I must admit it didn't cross my mind, as I'm lucky enough to have access through my university. However, in this case the paper is also available from [Yijie Han's website](http://welcome.to/yijiehan).

Comment: John Bartholomew, I asked not about textual description, but about implementation. Is there some?

Answer (score 0):

If memory usage is truly limited. I would separate each byte and store them into a trie data structure from most significant to least significant byte. If you insert the bytes in sorted order you can then iterate the trie and have all your data sorted.

Comment: what is time O() complexity? how much memory is needed

Comment: Well it depends, on how similar your keys are and what sorting algorithm you use on each byte. The wikipedia article will be able to explain its advantages better than I will.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 0):

Signature sort is good with large word sizes with 'O (n lg lg n)' expetcted time complexity, but with small word sizes you can get the same complexity with von Emde Boas sort. Also recently even faster sorting algorithm was published from Han and Thorup with 'O (n sqrt(lg lg n))' expected time complexity. I'm not sure if u can find implementations of these algorithms online, but there are probably some great articles and lectures on MIT and Harvard.

Answer (score -1):

I think the most reasonable thing to do is to create an array of pointers to the bigints, and sort the array of pointers.  I would suggest some sort of templated quicksort, with a smart compare function.

The compare function should be able to decide most of the time by looking at the most significant 4 bytes.  If they don't match, then the compare is decided.  If they do match then you look at the next 4 bytes until end of int.

I am guessing that the data range, is probably large enough, that a radix sort would be impractical.  Quick sort is generally faster enough if you data is random, and has cache performance that beats most non-radix sorts.

Comment: If you sort the pointers, you'll very probably have some serious cache locality problems I think, because you still need to randomly access 2Gb to perform the comparisions.

Comment: But when you do non local swaps (which you want, to minimize the number of swaps), you have with 2 GBs in all cases a cache locality problem. But with indirection of points you would at least avoid the huge amount of copying when swapping.

Comment: @g&f.  Yes, but....   You will have cache issues with every thing.  QuickSort eventually gets to the point where cache is effective.  Many other sorts do not.